# howTo get Image Resource of a ImageButton in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, imagebutton

i want change the ImageResource of a ImageButton that i have find by id.

## Motivation

a `ImageButton`(bottom) works as a reminder/backup of the last click of a `ImageButton`(top) .

### setup:

- some `ImageButton` (at the top of the app).
- a `ImageButton` (at the bottom of the app).

#### example without errors, but don't find ImageResource of idR1

```kotlin
findViewById<ImageButton>(idR1).setOnClickListener {
    findViewById<ImageButton>(idR5_oppCiv).setImageResource(R.drawable.athen_cavalry_swordsman);
```

#### not working examples

```kotlin
findViewById<ImageButton>(idR1).setOnClickListener {
    findViewById<ImageButton>(idR5_oppCiv).setImageResource(it.resources.getDrawable());
```

```kotlin
findViewById<ImageButton>(idR1).setOnClickListener {
    findViewById<ImageButton>(idR5_oppCiv).setImageResource(it.getImageResource());
```

#### try to get and set Drawable

following causes the app to crash when i click on an `ImageButton`.
Here i use a defType "res" to get the resource (the image hopefully).

```kotlin
val resR1: Int = resources.getIdentifier("r1col$i", "res", this.packageName)
findViewById<ImageButton>(idR1).setOnClickListener {
    findViewById<ImageButton>(idR5_oppCiv).setImageDrawable(getDrawable(resR1))
```

How could i get this image resource of it ? And use it for the other `ImageButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the image like using `setImageDrawable` like this.

```
    val image = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.your_view_id)
    image.setOnClickListener {
    findViewById<ImageButton>(idR5_oppCiv).setImageDrawable(image.drawable)
}
```

Comment: this gives me the error 'Unresolved reference: drawable' . it here has 'drawableState', 'drawableHotspotChanged()', dispatchDrawableHotspotChanged() jumpDrawablesToCurrentState() but no 'drawable'

Comment: Updated please check. You should reference of the view first